# Any way to simulate a material to look like the viewport?

Tags: shaders

I was wondering if there was anyway to get a material that looks like the matcap in eevee's viewport.

That kind of gradient look that catches shadows really well

[image]

Comment: Hello! Are you interested in hair in particular? I don't know how matcaps work with hair in 2.8, but for meshes be aware that, even if it might look like it's catching shadows, it's definitely *not* doing it! A matcap just assigns a color to each direction of the normals of faces (which can fake light direction) but objects don't see each other, nor they see their own parts.

Comment: Yeah I basically just want a material like kind of looks like this on my hair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make Your Own MatCaps Render Cycles**

```
In the Render Layer Node ( you just have to recharge the scene you're using )
```

Remember save file on .PNG
[image: Example]
[image: Method]
[image: MatCap]
[image]
[image]